# Dividing a array and storing in matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, math, matrix

I have an array `nMean_2` (*1*-by-*16320*), I want to divide it into 255 equal parts and store it in matrix (*64*-by-*255*)

```
mean2Electro = zeros(64,255);
r=1;

for z=1:64
mean2Electro(z,:)= nMean_2(r:((z*256)-1))
r= z*256;
end
```

But, I am getting an error:

> ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

in `mean2Electro` line.

Comment: Compare the values of `r` and `((z*256)-1)` - I'll bet there aren't `255` elements in the series

Comment: But also shouldn't you be using `reshape`?

Comment: @Dan newMean = reshape(nMean_2,[255,64])?

Comment: You still have to transpose: `reshape(nMean_2,255,64)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be self-contained, you can get your code working by fixing your loop:

```
mean2Electro = zeros(64,255);

for z=1:64
    mean2Electro(z,:)= nMean_2((z-1)*255 + 1:z*255);
end
```

However, I strongly advise the use of [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) as it's the most elegant way to do it, and the comments and accepted answer to your question use it.

---

Back to your problem, the way you were collecting chunks was not correct.  The only chunk that was valid was the first one.  In the end, you are collecting chunks of **256**, not 255.  Try displaying the beginning and ending index instead given your code:

```
r=1;

for z=1:64
    disp([r (z*256) - 1]);
    r= z*256;
end
```

We get this:

```
       1         255
     256         511
     512         767
     768        1023
    1024        1279
    1280        1535
    1536        1791
    1792        2047
    2048        2303
    2304        2559
    2560        2815
    2816        3071
    3072        3327
    3328        3583
    3584        3839
    3840        4095
    4096        4351
    4352        4607
    4608        4863
    4864        5119
    5120        5375
    5376        5631
    5632        5887
    5888        6143
    6144        6399
    6400        6655
    6656        6911
    6912        7167
    7168        7423
    7424        7679
    7680        7935
    7936        8191
    8192        8447
    8448        8703
    8704        8959
    8960        9215
    9216        9471
    9472        9727
    9728        9983
    9984       10239
   10240       10495
   10496       10751
   10752       11007
   11008       11263
   11264       11519
   11520       11775
   11776       12031
   12032       12287
   12288       12543
   12544       12799
   12800       13055
   13056       13311
   13312       13567
   13568       13823
   13824       14079
   14080       14335
   14336       14591
   14592       14847
   14848       15103
   15104       15359
   15360       15615
   15616       15871
   15872       16127
   16128       16383
```

Take note that the first chunk has 255 elements correctly.  However, the rest of the elements have **256** elements.  In general, to determine how many elements are within a range, you do `end - begin + 1`.

When you display the chunks with the corrected code:

```
for z = 1 : 64
    disp([(z-1)*255 + 1, z*255]);
end
```

We get:

```
       1         255
     256         510
     511         765
     766        1020
    1021        1275
    1276        1530
    1531        1785
    1786        2040
    2041        2295
    2296        2550
    2551        2805
    2806        3060
    3061        3315
    3316        3570
    3571        3825
    3826        4080
    4081        4335
    4336        4590
    4591        4845
    4846        5100
    5101        5355
    5356        5610
    5611        5865
    5866        6120
    6121        6375
    6376        6630
    6631        6885
    6886        7140
    7141        7395
    7396        7650
    7651        7905
    7906        8160
    8161        8415
    8416        8670
    8671        8925
    8926        9180
    9181        9435
    9436        9690
    9691        9945
    9946       10200
   10201       10455
   10456       10710
   10711       10965
   10966       11220
   11221       11475
   11476       11730
   11731       11985
   11986       12240
   12241       12495
   12496       12750
   12751       13005
   13006       13260
   13261       13515
   13516       13770
   13771       14025
   14026       14280
   14281       14535
   14536       14790
   14791       15045
   15046       15300
   15301       15555
   15556       15810
   15811       16065
   16066       16320
```

As you can see, each chunk has 255 elements exactly.

Comment: @HarshSharma - Thanks for accepting my answer :)  I'm not sure if that was a mistake or not.  Remember, you can only accept one answer.  If Navan's answer was more useful to you, you should accept his but I'm flattered that you changed your mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 255 elements in each selection then you should multiply by 255. When z becomes 2 you have 256 elements in the selection. As Dan mentioned it is easier to use reshape for this purpose.

```
mean2Electro = reshape(nMean_2,255,64)';
```

Comment: @what? so when z=2, it becomes [(2*256)-1] its 511. and 511-256 is 255 bro. :s

Comment: One note:  If you want MatLab to calculate the 2nd dimension you can give 
`mean2Electro = reshape(nMean_2, 255, [])`

Comment: @HarshSharma - If you want chunks of 255, you would want to have this relationship: `(z-1)*255 + 1: z*255`.  Substitute `z = 1, 2, 3` and you'll chunks of 255 correctly.

Comment: @rayryeng Man you never cease to amaze me :D, but i dont understand why my code showed matrix dimension error, when z=1:64 gives 255